# How do I alias the type of self in a struct method?

Tags: rust

If I have a small struct `Test`:

```
struct Test<T> { a: T }
```

And I wish, in a method of `Test` to refer to its full type:

```
impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn new(a: T) -> Test<T> {
        type X = Test::<T>;
        println!("{}", std::intrinsics::type_id::<X>());
        Test { a: a }
    }
}
```

This [fails](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=46e326cb57e181fd302b&version=stable) with *expected ident, found `<`*, and the following fail too:

- `type X = Test;`: *wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0 `[E0243]`*
- `type X = Test<T>;`: *can't use type parameters from outer function; try using a local type parameter instead* with a note *use of undeclared type name `T`*

Actually, it makes sense that the former two are rejected; the latter however is slightly more mysterious.

This came about in trying to implement an `offset_of!` macro: `offset_of($T:ty, $field:ident)`; the macro works rather well, however `ty` does not accept `Test<T>` (but accept a parameter-less alias).

Is there any way to either:

- craft an alias to the type of `self`, even in generics?
- or, alternatively, make it so that the macro accepts `Test<T>` as a "type" argument?

*Note: I would prefer a solution to the former, if possible, as aliases are really handy.*

---

For reference, here is the `offset_of` macro I crafted:

```
macro_rules! offset_of(
    ($T:ty, $field:ident) => {
        unsafe {
            let exemplar: $T = std::mem::uninitialized();
            let base: *const u8 = std::mem::transmute(&exemplar);
            let attr: *const u8 = std::mem::transmute(&exemplar.$field);
            std::mem::forget(exemplar);
            (attr as isize) - (base as isize)
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As a side note - the `$T` might be Droppable so you should probably at least forget it ([`std::mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html)).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: You are right, I actually the issue in actual code but never thought about coming back here and patching the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but there already is an alias for the type of self — `Self`:

```rust
#![feature(core)]

struct Test<T> { a: T }

impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn new(a: T) -> Test<T>
        where T: 'static
    {
        println!("{}", unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_id::<Self>() });
        Test { a: a }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I had to add the feature gates, make `T` `'static` to satisfy `type_id`, and add an unsafe block. I hope that none of that seems suspicious. This seems to work with your alias, as well:

```rust
macro_rules! offset_of(
    ($T:ty, $field:ident) => {
        unsafe {
            let exemplar: $T = std::mem::uninitialized();
            let base: *const u8 = std::mem::transmute(&exemplar);
            let attr: *const u8 = std::mem::transmute(&exemplar.$field);
            (attr as isize) - (base as isize)
        }
    }
);

struct Test<T> { a: T, b: T, c: T }

impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn new(a: T) -> Test<T>
        where T: Copy
    {
        println!("{}", offset_of!(Self, a));
        println!("{}", offset_of!(Self, b));
        println!("{}", offset_of!(Self, c));
        Test { a: a, b: a, c: a }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Test::new(1u16);
}
```

Comment: Ah! No you are not misunderstanding. I tested `Self` in the alias and `type X = Self;` did not compile (*use of undeclared type name `Self`*) so I did not think about testing it in the macro. I guess 1.0 has many inconsistencies still.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that seems a little strange and it may be worth filing an issue. At least there is a workaround for now!

Comment: I guess technically my answer *isn't* an answer to your question, it's just a solution to your problem...